# ADF test with large time series dataset (over 1m rows) python

Tags: time-series, python, large-data, augmented-dickey-fuller

I am currently working on two stock price data. The dataset has over 1m rows, consisting of a minute wise change for 2 years. To check if the two stock price change movements are related, I want to conduct cross correlation.

Before I do normalized cross correlation, it seemed stationary check is required.

I tried KPSS and ADF test, but ADF test gives out an error regarding out of memory while KPSS had no problem. I processed the dataset to reduce memory spending, but then it takes forever to get the result. (I waited 40 min. still not seeing the result.) I guess, ADF test python library is not for large dataset like mine.

I would like to know if there's a workaround to deal with memory and speed problem when doing ADF test in python. Also, if there's another way to test trend stationary like ADF, I would like to know what it is.

Comment: Stackoverflow might be a better venue to ask this as it is related to software performance.

Comment: Or use `R`. `microbenchmark::microbenchmark(tseries::adf.test(cumsum(rnorm(1e6))), times = 1)` tells me that such a test takes around 13 seconds on my fairly standard desktop PC. The ADF test is nothing but a standard t-statistic, which should be able to handle such a dataset. This is actually even when performing a search for an optimal lag length. If you fix the lag length it does not even take a second.

Comment: Hypothesis testing on such a large dataset is rarely useful.  You can almost guarantee the test will find evidence of *some* non-stationary, perhaps of tiny magnitude.  This suggests you reconsider what you are doing and focus on procedures that would be relevant for whatever your study objective might be.

Answer (score 1):

Consider aggregating the data to a lower frequency, e.g. to daily data. When testing properties such as presence of a unit root, what matters is the time span, not the frequency at which the data is sampled. Unless the sample is too small for asymptotic inference, that is.

See Giles ["Unit Root Testing: Sample Size vs. Sample Span"](http://davegiles.blogspot.no/2014/05/unit-root-testing-sample-size-vs-sample.html) and ["The Econometrics of Temporal Aggregation - IV - Cointegration"](http://davegiles.blogspot.no/2014/09/the-econometrics-of-temporal.html#more) and Cochran ["Unit Roots, Redux"](https://johnhcochrane.blogspot.com/2015/04/unit-roots-redux.html#more) for more detail.